# Dynamically creating menu links from a node's fields

Tags: views, nodes

I have to first, create a menu-like block based on the information in a content type. Below every link, there is a text area field from a content type (*Conference*) except for upcoming conferences and archived conferences. So basically, each link in the menu is a view that shows only one particular field from a node. I pretty much got that part down.

Next I needed the ability for these menus to be dynamically created whenever I created a piece of content. So the 8th annual conference should have a menu created due to the fields in the *Conference* content type being populated.

Does anyone know an approach to dynamically create these menus links when a node is added? The approach I took so far was trying to add arguments that could be used in the view based on the node ID.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module and also use [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) which gives lot of options to display your content. Check out the image, it was created using field group.

[image]

Comment: That part about using a view block I have so far. For me this works only when when there is one node. How can I pass an argument to the Menu view block to let it know that I want the "7th National Conference" and not 8th, Because when I click on each link I still want that menu to be there for that particular convention.

I would like to note that you did answer the question I would just like more details on how to implement what you were saying. 

Also I would like to note that each link on the menu is being pulled from conference content type except the first and last three.

Comment: If you create a new conference, 8th, then do you want to create a new menu link like `8th conference` or you want to replace it under `upcoming conference`

Comment: For that Page I would Place it under, I imagine for that the VIEW-Page, upcoming-conference I would display all conferences. That particular page I'm not that worried about. My concern is with the other links that should only show information about that one confernce.

Comment: Lets say the url is Site.com/conference-name/schedule (the 2nd link), How can I get the menu to only link to pages under that conference's name. Basically how can I get it to also link to Site.com/conference-name/registration. And also stay visible while so I see all those links for that conference after clicking each link.

Comment: Can you describe your menu structure again because the menu that you posted has only one conference link, others are like speakers etc.

Comment: okie dokie. Basically would I like the menu to pull data from the content-type node **conferences**. Each link (with the exception on _upcoming conferences_, _be-a-sponsor_, _past-sponsors_, and _conference-archive_) will link to a view-page that is only showing one field from the node. So **conferences** has a Schedule Field, a keynote speaker, so on and so forth.

Comment: Now I get it, for this you don't need menu. Just group the fields into different fieldset and use CSS to show as tab. You can use Display Suite module which let you do these things easily.

Comment: How can I get this menu to show the links for this content,for instance to the Schedule page for just a certain piece of content, and the menu still remain visible after I click on a link so I can still choose keynote speaker for the same piece of content.

Comment: ok. I will look at that module to see if it helps. Thank You.

Comment: I have updated the answer, check out

Comment: I think I just be explaining things wrong. It seem Display suite helps you organize content cleanly and in a organize way. That's not what I need.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Fields Group module is the one which allows you to group fields and show in horizontal/vertcal tabs.

Comment: I have added an image showing what you can accomplish using Field Group.

Comment: I appreciate you, This won't really work for this site because I need links that are generated both from the Content Node, and Static Links. This module will definitely help me in the Future. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

Though this may not be the best practice, I wound up creating views that had exposed filters using the node ID. From there I just added the field I wanted visible then overrode the output link to include the exposed filter.

Comment: `Panels` module might also help, check it out